# limit of $=\frac{1}{n}\int_{1/n}^{1}\ln(1+\cos x) dx$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations

Prove that sequence $(I_{n})_{n\geq 1}$, $I_{n} = \frac{1}{n}\int_{1/n}^{1}\ln(1+\cos x) dx$ is convergent and find the limit.

Comment: It tends to $0$ because $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \ln(1+\cos x)\ \mathrm dx$ is finite and is a constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that, since the integrand is non-negative, we have
$$
0< I_n\le \frac1n\cdot \int_0^{1}\ln(1+\cos x) dx\le \frac{1}n \cdot \ln 2
$$ conclude with the sandwich theorem.